# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined in angular 2 with patternlab

Tags: angular2-forms, patternlab.io

I am using patternlab with angular 2 and in forms of angular 2 get the next error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined
>       at Object.View_CriticalInfoComponent_37._co [as updateDirectives] (icancer_critical_info.html:390)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (services.ts:443)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:359)
>       at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:726)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:410)
>       at callViewAction (view.ts:767)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (view.ts:726)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (view.ts:410)
>       at callViewAction (view.ts:767)

Comment: Elaborate your question a little more.

Comment: i am using patternlab with angular 2 and in forms of angular 2 its showing error Cannot read property 'touched' of undefined